# Position Div vertically down or up using CSS

Tags: html, css

How to position the Div inside div vertically down or top.
 
Here What I have done so far.

```css
.lovecolbanner {
 margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row_bottom">
       <div class="lovecolbanner">
<span class="lovecolumnbanner">Love Column</span>

                     </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <div class="pickup_item">
                <a href="http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/user_data/post06">
                    <div class="item_photo"><img src="{{ app.config.front_urlpath }}/img/column/09.jpg"></div>
                    <dl>
                        <dt class="item_name text-warning">恋愛やダイエットに関わる脳内物質</dt>
                        
                        <dd class="more_link text-warning">read more</dd>
                    </dl>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <div class="pickup_item">
                <a href="http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/user_data/post02">
                    <div class="item_photo"><img src="{{ app.config.front_urlpath }}/img/column/08.jpg"></div>
                    <dl>
                        <dt class="item_name text-warning">未婚じゃなくて、非婚です！</dt>
                        
                        <dd class="more_link text-warning">read more</dd>
                    </dl>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <div class="pickup_item">
                <a href="http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/user_data/post08">
                    <div class="item_photo"><img src="{{ app.config.front_urlpath }}/img/column/10.jpg"></div>
                    <dl>
                        <dt class="item_name text-warning">男性脳と女性脳（１）すれ違いが起きる原因</dt>
                        
                        <dd class="more_link text-warning">read more</dd>
                    </dl>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   

    </div>
        
    
</div>
```

I will be keeping banners image in place of "love column" text 
 So for now that is just references. 
Also When I do the padding top, Whole Div `row_bottom` moves down. 
[image]

Update :
Changed span to div class and tried the following css, but It didnt give me what I wanted.

```css
.lovecolumnbanner {
    border: 4px solid pink;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
}
```

After update pic
[image]

Comment: Not clearly understand what you want to achieve

Comment: I have added an image too. I want that "love column" text which is inside the div".lovecolbanner" to move down . @Chaska

Comment: How about try using `<div>` instead of `<span>` for `.lovecolumnbanner` and set its top and bottom padding?

Comment: @Chaska I did what you said and have updated the post with updated screenshot too. As you can see I cannot still bring that div down. I want to bring Love column with border bit down. I did margin top, but whole row_bottom is coming down :/

Answer (score 0):

Using `position:relative` and `top:xx%` solved it .
Thank you